# Flowing/floating text layers inside symbols

Tags: sketch-app

One symbol consisting of two text layers in Sketch, one text layer above the other.

If the top text layer has long text and goes onto multiple lines, can the bottom text layer move down somehow without overlapping? Ideally, the original gap between the two text layers should remain the same.

[image: I've made an animated gif that illustrates the problem. If the text in the top layer is edited it would be great if Sketch were able to push the text below down]

This illustrates the problem - ideally the "text layer two" should move down automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Stacks** from the **Anima Auto Layout plugin** to achieve this. It's a crazy sketch plugin that can do many things. The whole plugin suite is called Launchpad. But you want to take a look at Stacks in the Auto Layout module.

Here is a video showing how it works and you can see this action:

https://youtu.be/DiCXg17CwIY

You can download it from this link:

https://animaapp.github.io/Auto-Layout/